# CSS and HTML rollover and display active target

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, target

I'm attempting to create a menu for a site without JS where the menu is hidden, revealed on rollover, and remains open when clicked. I found a site that teaches the basics of attaching a :target class to activate a revealed state but when trying to add a :hover effect it seems to over-ride. Here's the JSFIDDLE link::

http://jsfiddle.net/shadna/NTXbz/

Here's the HTML::

```
<p>
  <a href="#item1">item 1</a>
  <a href="#item2">item 2</a>
  <a href="#item3">item 3</a>
  <a href="#default">clear</a>

<div class="items">
  <p id="item1">... item 1...
  <p id="item2">... item 2...
  <p id="item3">...
  <p id="default"><!-- by default, show no text -->
</div>
```

Here's the CSS::

```
div.items p:not(:target) {display: none}
div.items p:target {display: block}
div.items p a:hover {display: block}
```

Thanks!

S

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way, you need to hover over the `<p>` itself, here's something to [TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/NTXbz/6/)

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. I'll try working it out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `div.items p a:hover {display: block}` won't work because the `.items div` is set to `display:none`. Hidden items do not respond to `:hover` pseudo selectors.

Also I don't think the HTML structure you have will allow hover to work the way you want to  because there is no way to tell the target `#item` that it's activation link `href="#item"` is being hovered over.

You can achieve the result using a list though: http://jsfiddle.net/Peteor/KcGCZ/ as this allows you to show a child element when a parent is hovered.

```
.menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```